# How to Declare/Define and simultaneously Select multiple cells/ranges in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Below is the problematic part of my code. The code takes in the ProductCode and the Quantity through the InputBox, however, once the ProductcCode is entered, I also want it to define store the values, "Cost" and "Discount" that are beside it so they can be displayed in my final Input Box. Any help would be greatly Appreciated.

```
'Obtaining VLookup Value
ProductCode = InputBox("Enter the ProductCode's code.")

'Error checking
Do Until ErrorCheck = False
    If ProductCode = "" Then
        ErrorCheck = True
        MsgBox ("Not a valid entry.")
        ProductCode = InputBox("Enter the ProductCode's code.")
        Cost = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        MinQty = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        Discount = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
    ElseIf IsError(Application.VLookup(ProductCode, myRange, 3, False)) Then
        ErrorCheck = True
        MsgBox ("The value entered was not found.")
        ProductCode = InputBox("Enter the ProductCode's code.")
    Else
        ErrorCheck = False
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your narrative isn't very clear and also conflicts with part of your code, but I think O got the whole idea

so you may try and adapt this (commented) code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Product()
    Dim ProductCode  As String
    Dim ErrorCheck As Boolean
    Dim Cost As Double, MinQty As Double, Discount As Double
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim found As Variant

    Set MyRange = Range("A1:A10") '<-- change it to your actual "MyRange" setting

    Do '"main" outer loop
        Do '"Product code input" inner loop
            ProductCode = Application.InputBox("Enter the ProductCode's code.", Type:=2) '<--| force string input
        Loop While ProductCode = ""

        found = Application.Match(ProductCode, MyRange.Columns(1), 0) '<-- try getting ow index of prodcut code in 1st column of "MyRange" range
        If IsError(found) Then '<--| if no match found...
            MsgBox "The value entered was not found!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please, try again", vbCritical + vbOKOnly '<-- inform the user and loop again
        Else '<--| otherwise
            With MyRange(found, 1) '<-- reference the matching cell
                Cost = .Offset(0, 1).Value '<--| store "Cos"t from cell 1 column to the right of the referenced one
                MinQty = .Offset(0, 2).Value '<--| store "MinQty" from cell 2 columns to the right of the referenced one
                Discount = .Offset(0, 3).Value '<--| store "Discount" from cell 3 columns to the right of the referenced one
            End With
        End If
    Loop While IsError(found)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you So much. this worked tremendously. Could I also ask, how could I place my whole code in a For loop, that asks the user for the number of different products purchased??.  That is, each time through the loop I get information about a particular product purchased.

Comment: You are welcome. As per this site rules 1) new issues must be posted in new questions with your code attempts 2) please mark my answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thank you